# Laravel 5.3 Route model binding with multiple parameters

Tags: laravel-routing, laravel-5.3

Is it possible to have route model binding using multiple parameters? For example

**Web Routes:**

```
Route::get('{color}/{slug}','Products@page');
```

So `url` `www.mysite.com/blue/shoe` will be binded to `shoe` Model, which has `color` blue.

Comment: I Changed question to be more explicit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, it would feel more natural to have a route like the following:

```
Route::get('{product}/{color}', 'Products@page');
```

and to resolve `product` by route binding, and just use the `color` parameter in the controller method directly, to fetch a list of blue shoes for example.

But let's assume that for some reason it's a requirement. I'd make your route a bit more explicit, to start with:

```
Route::get('{color}/{product}', 'Products@page');
```

Then, in the `boot` method of `RouteServiceProvider.php`, I would add something like this:

```
Route::bind('product', function ($slug, $route) {
    $color = $route->parameter('color');

    return Product::where([
        'slug'  => $slug,
        'color' => $color,
    ])->first() ?? abort(404);
});
```

`first` here is important, because when resolving route models like that you effectively want to return a single model.

That's why I think it doesn't make much sense, since what you want is probably a list of products of a specific color, not just a single one.

Anyways, I ended up on this question while looking for a way to achieve what I demonstrated above, so hopefully it will help someone else.

Comment: This answers the question. However, I am kind a puzzled, why you dont use firstOrFail() method instead of abort(404)?

Comment: @Fusion that’s the way it is handled in the official doc, I assume `abort(404)` returns a proper 404 response. Would need to check what `findOrFail` does exactly, not sure the response would be the same

Comment: @Fusion just realised you meant `firstOrFail`. Does that method even exist? (Can’t check right now)

Comment: both findOrFail() and firstOrFail() exist. I preffer using firstOrFail() looks like they do the same thing.

Comment: @Fusion cool. Don’t forget to accept my answer if you think it addresses your question correctly

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to declare the parameter types:

```
Route::delete('safedetail/{safeId}/{slug}', [
    'as' => 'safedetail.delete',
    'uses' => 'SafeDetailController@destroy',
])->where([
    'safeId' => '[0-9]+',
    'slug' => '[a-z]+',
]);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try changing your controller to this:

```
class Pages extends Controller{

    public function single($lang, App\Page $page){

        dd($page);

    }

}
```

You must add the Page Model.