# Route model binding route with hash and slug parameters

Tags: laravel, model, routes

Say I have some routes:

```
 Route::get('items', 'ItemController@index')->name('item.index');
 Route::get('items/{hash}/{slug}', 'ItemController@show')->name('item.show');
```

While using route model binding I want to handle the following cases:

- `/items/<correct_hash>/<incorrect_slug>` permanent redirect to correct hash and slug
- `/items/<correct_hash>` permanent redirect to correct hash and slug
- Anything else redirect to `/items/`

I currently understand the shortcut benefit of route model binding which reduces controller code but is typically used for a simple `/items/{id}` cases. Is it possible to extend what is shown in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#explicit-binding) for my case? Or should I scrap the entire model binding approach and go back to caveman controller logic?

Currently it seems the documentation can only bind one parameter at a time not a combination:

```
    Route::bind('user', function ($value) {
        return App\User::where('name', $value)->first() ?? abort(404);
    });
```

Comment: AFAIK is not possible to define a route mode binding, implicit or explicit, with more than one parameter. IMHO that is a very difficult route to follow, you'll have to fight against ton of already written code, RESTful resources usually do follow the one parameter way, being it id or slug.

Comment: @dparoli I have done some searching in the meantime, apparently it might be possible to have multiple parameters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39289608/laravel-5-3-route-model-binding-with-multiple-parameters. I'll try this out to see if it's true for 5.8 release.

Comment: Good luck, in case you solve you can answer your own question.